# PayUMoney redirecting page after successful transaction

Tags: android, redirect, transactions, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am developing a sample application with PayUMoney Transaction. The app functions well. But I am looking for redirecting the page to an Activity after the successful transaction. I am using payUMoney SDK Does anyone gone through this? Please guide me.. any kind of help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the similar issue.I assume you have integrated payUMoney using sdk. Your sdk will be having a WebViewActivity which is used to redirect user to success/failure screen after transcation has been completed. Add a button on server side naming "ok" or "continue" on success/failure url screen.Detect click of that button in your SDK's WebView Activity and finish the activity.

Ask your web developer to add an html button on success/failure url:

```
<button type="button" onclick="ok.performClick();">OK</button>
```

This is how you can detect click on an html button in WebViewActivity of your SDK:

```
 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
            mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
            {
                @JavascriptInterface
                public void performClick(String status)
                {
                    // Deal with a click on the OK button
                    //    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Payment Success",2000).show();
                    //  Log.e("status payment-------->",status);
                    finish();

                }
            }, "ok");
```

Comment: Thanks nidhi for your reply i will try it

Comment: I have tried but didn't work can you elaborate it little more.

Comment: I have tried but didn't work can you elaborate it little more. This is my php code for button     $hash = hash("sha512", $retHashSeq);
   echo "<h3>Thank You. Your order status is ". $status .".</h3>";
          echo "<h4>Your Transaction ID for this transaction is ".$txnid.".</h4>";
          echo "<h4>We have received a payment of Rs. " . $amount . ". Your order will soon be shipped.</h4>";
    echo "<button>Continue</button>";
and i have add your code in android activity  same as above

Comment: You have to get the click of button on same name which you have assigned while creating it. In case of my example , it is "ok". Please see my edit.

Comment: My pleasure.Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution on the android and the HTML side code, also we can detect the value of the HTML button in android

Android Code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView mWebView=findViewById(R.id.webView_paypal);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.21:8081/DeepLinking/");
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
    {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick(String strl)
        {
            Log.e("TAG ","HTML Button Value : "+strl);
        }
    }, "btn_success");
}
 }
```

HTML

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Page</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<br>
<button type="button_Success" value="Success" onclick="btn_success.performClick(this.value);">Success</button>
<br/>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(paymentParam,
                        getActivity(), R.style.AppTheme_default, true);
```

Use third params(isOverrideResultScreen) as true